# Change dynamic source data for pivot table Excel Macro

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I've created a macro that auto updates/changes the source data of my pivot.

The problem with my macro is the source data is not static. The number of rows in trialbalance sheet changes daily so the cell reference `A1:F500` is not applicable to what I'm trying to achieve.

The number of column is fixed always (columns A to F).

If someone could lend his or her helping hand on how can I detect how to get the top up to the bottom of the report found in the trialbalance sheet? That would be great!

```
Sheets("mtd move").pivottables("pvtmtd").SourceData = Sheets("trialbalance").[A1:F500].CurrentRegion.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
```

Comment: Put the data in a table and point the pivot st it. The source will now be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment above, @DougGlancy has a great suggestion. If you are stuck with an older version of Excel that does not support the built-in `Table` construct, you could use the following to identify the last row, then wrap the entire data block in a `Range`:

```
'...
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim PivotSource As Range
With Sheets("trialbalance")
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set PivotSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 6)) '<~ col F = 6
End With
```

You now have a `Range` object that contains all the data on the "trialbalance" sheet, i.e. all the cells from A1 (`.Cells(1, 1)` in the snippet above) to the last occupied row in column F (`.Cells(LastRow, 6)` in the above code).